# Write a SQL Statement which displays the name of each teacher, together with the name of his/her reporting officer

Tags: mysql

I have a trouble in doing the 3rd question, i think i should use inner join but i cant get it correctly. need some help. here is the sql.

```
CREATE TABLE TeacherInfomation
(
TeacherName nvarchar(100),
TeacherID nvarchar(10),
ReportingOfficerID nvarchar(10),
primary key(TeacherName,TeacherID)
);

INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Queenie','213P','204P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Rachel','225P','204P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Sarah','278P','254P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Tina','290P','245P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Violet','300T','213P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Wesley','301T','225P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Xena','204P','200P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Yvonne','245P','200P')
INSERT INTO TeacherInfomation VALUES ('Zachary','200P','NULL')

1) SELECT * FROM TeacherInfomation

2) SELECT TeacherName FROM TeacherInfomation WHERE TeacherID LIKE '%P'

Question im stuck at 3) SELECT COUNT(TeacherName) AS TotalNumberOfTeachers,ReportingOfficerID FROM TeacherInfomation GROUP BY ReportingOfficerID
```

[QuestionPaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAJjR.png)

Comment: so what you want??

Comment: try this.......SELECT ReportingOfficerID , COUNT(TeacherName)  FROM TeacherInfomation GROUP BY ReportingOfficerID

Comment: This is the question Write a SQL Statement which displays the name of each teacher, together with the name of his/her reporting officer

Comment: @denny i have added the image of the question

Comment: `primary key(TeacherName,TeacherID)` looks wrong. Probably TeacherName is Functionally Dependent on on TeacherID (which in that case should be the PK)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my primary key error. :) my bad. @wildplasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query sholud be like this

```
      select 
      p1.TeacherName,p1.TeacherID,p1.ReportingOfficerID,p2.TeacherName 
      from TeacherInfomation p1 
      join TeacherInfomation p2 on p1.TeacherID = p2.ReportingOfficerID
```

Comment: THANK YOU DENNY! i managed to try it on my own after seeing your solution and understood the statement well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Question is to show all teachers with their reporting officers. So we don't need any `count` or `group by`

Here what I tried :

```
select ti.TeacherName ri.ReportingOfficerName
from TeacherInformation ti
left join TeacherInfomation ri on ri.TeacherId = ti.ReportingOfficerId
```

We need to add self join as ReportingOfficer too because teacherId and reportingOfficierId are matching.

Comment: Thank you nazeed for your help. @denny gave me the correct solution. :)